# Highcharts thousandsSep is blank instead comma

Tags: highcharts

I am add option

```
lang: {
    thousandsSep: ","
},
```

and

```
format: '{value:,.0f}'
```

but it's show blank instead comma

https://jsfiddle.net/cpmh8f24/3/
this my chart sample

Answer (score 0):

It's work:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang : {
            thousandsSep:','
           }
 });
```